# How to allow anonymous user for checkout process?

Tags: commerce

When users buy one of our offers (premium offer), the site will create a user account, send a link to his/her account to reset the password, etc.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Make sure [Commerce Checkout Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect) is enabled

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the permission, under `Admin > People > Permissions : "Access checkout"` for anonymous users.

If the user does login, their anonymous order will be added to their authenticated user cart.